# Maximo readonly/persistent attribute issues

Tags: maximo

I have an non-persistent attribute (SITEID) on my WOCHANGE object that originates from the parent object, WORKORDER. For some particular reason, this attribute has a few problems that I've never really seen with other attributes before.

Based on various configurations I have tried in an attempt to remedy the issue, here are the main issues:

- It doesn't trigger the WOCHANGE to save when changed.
- In addition to the value not being saved, I can change the value on one record, go to another and the value persists on the different record.
- The field is readonly unless I define it to have an inputmode of DEFAULT. This is odd to me, because not defining inputmode usually implies default behavior (NOT readonly).

Here are the definitions for the SITEID attribute on both the WORKORDER

[image]

and WOCHANGE objects.

[image]

SITEID also uses a TABLE domain belonging to the SITE table.

Are there any attribute rules being applied from other sources that I should be checking?

Answer (score 0):

That workorder field class on there may not be desired and may be messing with things, like setting the field to read-only. Site Id is commonly a read-only field, especially when the record is no longer a new record. Because of that, the logic to make that field read-only could be buried deeper in the Maximo business logic than just that field class. You are working with a field that has a lot of special meaning in Maximo, you are likely going to stumble into many built-in business rules.

Since non-persistent fields are *not* saved in the database (they are in memory fields only), I don't believe they trigger the flag for a record to be saved. What would be saved? Nothing in the database (a save) is to be changed yet.

Your screenshot however shows the field as persistent. Is WOCHANGE a view? I can't recall and no longer have the resources to check.

Comment: Yes, WOCHANGE is a view. Here's the SQL to create it for Maximo 7.5.0.8: http://pastebin.com/7JMmDwrS

Comment: Thanks. I see that the SITEID field is a persistent field on the view. You might want to edit your original question, since you state the field is non-persistent.
I still believe that field class is causing some of the problems, but you probably really do want that field read-only. You usually can't change the SITEID in Maximo once the record is saved. If this field was editable, how do you plan to handle that contradiction?
The view could be causing the save problems, but again, you would probably need some extra code to allow that field to modified anyway (as per above).